# AJAX HTTP post request is triggered 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my webapp, the Ajax request is executed 3 times, and I have no idea why this is happening.
Can someone please help here?

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");


  $('form').on('submit', function(e) { //
  e.preventDefault();
  // on form submission ...    
    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="perfid"]').val();
    valueTwo = $('input[name="hostname"]').val();
    valueThree = $('input[name="iteration"]').val();


    console.log(valueOne)
    console.log(valueTwo)
    console.log(valueThree)



    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      dataType:'json',
      data : { 'first': valueOne,'second': valueTwo,'third': valueThree},
      success: function(data) {

       var res = data.AVG;
       var p = '<p><pre>'+res+'</pre></p>';
       $('#result').append(p);

      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });
 });  });
```

And my HTML is:

```
 <form role="form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="perfid" name="perfid" placeholder="Enter a Perf ID" required style="height:30px;">
                                <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="hostname" name="hostname" placeholder="Enter a HostName"  style="height:30px;">
                                <input type="text" class="input-medium" id="iteration" name="iteration" placeholder="Enter a Iteration" required style="height:30px;">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="height:30px;">Get Data</button>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

I have written the code for only one AJAX POST request,

EDIT:

This is the console output:
[image]

Comment: do you get the console.log values only once?

Comment: how many `<form>` tags are in your HTML source?  At a glance, nothing looks incorrect.

Comment: @Clayton

The code has Only one <form> tag , I have included that in the Question.

Comment: If you set an id on the form `<form id="myForm"  ...>` and reference it as `$('#myForm')` does that change anything?  It shouldn't be necessary to call `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure you have included the js file only once, 
and add a `return false` at the end of the submit event callback

Comment: Hey this was it.
By mistake my I included the JS file 3 times (Copy Paste Error :( )


Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

look at the selector

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
```

if  the page has 3 forms, the above selector will execute 3 times
Try to add id to the form like this. sorry about my bad english

Comment: If 3 form is there then the call back will fire on each form's submit only once, not 3 time on every form submit